# Backup myIsam .MYD only

Tags: mysql, backup, myisam

Is it possible to backup the .MYD file only? (and rebuild the .MYI if/when there is a catastrophic failure)

---

I'd like to backup rather large tables offsite while minimizing bandwidth usage. Data is critical, index files (5G+) are not. The idea is to run regular backups of the .frm and .myd files and rebuild the indexes iff there were a catastrophic failure (i.e. local backups destroyed by fire or stolen).

Repair with .frm and .myd only gives me an error message. Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: If you're using MyISAM you're in for a world of hurt if your table gets corrupted and the last thing you need to do is be all clever and not back up **everything**. MySQL makes no guarantees that the files on disk are in a consistent state, `mysqldump` is really the only way to ensure it's coherent.

Comment: If as you say ___Data is critical___ dont mess with standard techniques of backup. If you do you will need to TEST TEST TEST it

Comment: If someone here said "_Yes thats cool go ahead_" Would you believe them without testing it? I hope not, so test it and see

Comment: As @tadman says, just back up your data the normal way.  Not only is it the right plan, but it also neets all of your requirements:  In most cases, the dump file will be smaller than the original tablespace.  The dump file contains no copies of the indexes, and loading the dump file will of course rebuild the indexes.   Is there a reason you can think of **not** to do that?  (Also, MyISAM should never be used for critical data.)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Double emphasis on **MyISAM should never be used for critical data**. This is important as well. Explanation: It's not journaled, it's terrible at recovering from faults, and it doesn't support transactions, making it brittle at best and dangerously flawed by design.

Comment: My question wasn't about MyIsam vs other engines. Our use case leads us to favour MyIsam for a variety of reasons.

I couldn't find evidence to the effect that MyIsam is deprecated. For a more balanced comparison between MyIsam and InnoDB, you may want to look at this https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-engines-myisam-vs-innodb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully restore a MyIsam table without the .MYI (i.e. solely from the .frm and the .myd files), run:

`REPAIR tableName USE_FRM;`

---

To make a fast and compact backup of the structure+data, run:

```
FLUSH TABLES tableName WITH READ LOCK;
```

[make a copy of the .frm and .myd files. No need to copy the .myi]

```
UNLOCK TABLES
```

Copying the .myd file provides a much faster backup than using mysqldump, for large tables. I ran a quick test and a 6G table took 6 minutes to backup with mysqldump vs a 5 seconds direct copy. The mysqldump file was the combined size of the myd+myi files. The .myd file can/should be compressed (I use 7z).

Direct copy is one of the several backup methods discussed in MySQL's official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/backup-methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

No.  You must also dump the `.frm` so that the schema is captured.  Yes, the `.MYI` can be recreated.  Yeah, "repair with .frm and .MYD" should work; I have never tested it.  You could test it by stopping MySQL, copying those two files to a different database, then trying the repair.

MyISAM is not only deprecated, it is gone from the next release (8.0).  There is essentially no valid reason for using MyISAM in the future.  And many reasons for not using it.

If the .MYI file is bigger than  the .MYD file, you *may* be doing something wrong.  A small percentage of tables do have more indexes than data, but is it is somewhat rare.  When someone says "I indexed every column", then I know he is a novice and does not understand that:

- Indexes on flags (and other low-cardinality columns) will probably never be used.
- "Composite" indexes are often useful.
- MySQL rarely uses two indexes in the same `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize bandwidth usage, I can suggest a few other possible strategies:

- Use mysqldump, since the output contains only data, no index content. Indexes will be recreated when you restore the dump.
- Compress the backup, then transfer the compressed file. It may be 1/10th the size of an uncompressed backup.
- Use replication, so only incremental changes to your database are transferred to your other site. Then run backups on the replica.

It's not safe for your data integrity to do "backups" by copying files out of the data directory. You should use a backup tool like mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create an empty table like the one to be protected.

For the backup:

1) create an empty table like the original
2) backup the original .frm & .MYD
3) include the empty .MYI in the backup set
4) drop the empty table


The recovery steps:

1) Restore the table (the original .frm & .MYD and the empty .MYI restored to same database as the .frm & .MYD)
   2) lock the table to prevent its use
   3) run myisamchk (I prefer to run from the OS - index regeneration can be parallelized and analyzed for optimizer statistics)
   4) flush table table (needed if repairing from the OS)
   5) unlock the table
   6) analyze the table (if optimizer statistics need to be gathered)